# What technique wordpress use for reset password?

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

I tried to reset password of wordpress admin panel.

I type some password and select function MD5.

It shows exact md5 conversion of the given string.

After log-in in admin panel of wordpress, if we browse the table it converts the password in some other string.

Can any one guide me about the password technique ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd certainly hope that wordpress was using something other than a basic md5 hash.... but why do you need to know the actual method that it uses? Is this for a security audit or similar?

Comment: Nothing special, I just want to know that what exactly they are using. because after log-in into the admin panel, the string updated in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password)

> Creates a hash of a plain text password. Unless the global $wp_hasher is set, the default implementation uses PasswordHash, which adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5. MD5 is used by default because it's supported on all platforms. You can configure PasswordHash to use Blowfish or extended DES (if available) instead of MD5 with the $portable_hashes constructor argument or property (see examples).

Comment: Thanks Mark, got it. :)

Comment: By the way, what could be the reason to update this string at log-in time. (Means in db, I typed a string 'admin' and md5 in function. It saves exact simple md5. after first log-in, I browse the db table and string updated. while before log-in string was simple md5. )

Comment: Probably some form of backward compatibility for those days when md5 was believed to be a secure hash, so it allows old passwords that are simple md5 hashes to verify.... but updates it with the additional 7 md5s on login - would be my guess.... but you'd really need to ask the person who wrote it to know what they were thinking when they did it

Comment: OK sure. I will ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

It uses the [wp_hash_password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) function.

```
function wp_hash_password($password) {
    global $wp_hasher;

    if ( empty($wp_hasher) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php');
        // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    }   
    return $wp_hasher->HashPassword( trim( $password ) );
}
```

The source coude of the "class-phpass.php" file can be found on the site: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/class-phpass.php